# Connection pool for per application server instead of per application

Tags: glassfish, connection-pooling

I would like to replace glassfish connection pool with another connection pool implementation in order to create more dynamic configurations. I have a lot application at the same server. I do not want to create a connection pool for each application because of the connection count can be dramatically increase by the application count. What is the best way in order to provide a common application pool for the application server. Maybe as a side note I am using Spring and BoneCP will be used as a connection pool replacement.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Also added a little more description.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you want to use a pool shared by all apps, then it must be done from within the appserver's config, and that means using glassfish's own pooling mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Skaffman. Publishing beans as jndi resource with spring than before creating a connection pool checking again existence of a connection pool with spring seems fine. What about your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can exchange the internal connection pool of an application server. It sounds like exchanging some internals that aren't meant to be exchanged. However you can just ignore the application server connection pool and use your own connection pool.

One of my colleages was using DBCP in his projects so that the testcases can be run without an JNDI connection. He just initiated the connections directy with his spring context through dbcp.

The downside with this solution is that you will loose the central application server configuration facility.